# Does the time constant of a thermometer or a thermocouple change with temperature?

Tags: thermodynamics

It seems likely to me that it should remain constant(given a fixed setup and surface area of heat transmission), dependent on the material of the thermometer in question as the time constant Tao equals the sensor's heat capacity divided by total thermal conductance of the system.

If not, how could we go about calculating this change other than by experimental data?

Comment: I would said it depends on T range.  But if technical,  thermometers have an operational range within all should be fine

Comment: The time constant presumably depends on the system's geometry, density, thermal conductivity, heat capacity, convection, radiation, and many other factors. Why wouldn't it change with temperature?